# I've got an issue doing validations by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I validate any textbox by using ID or type (in jQuery) etc. like:

```
var element=document.getElementById('tbxSearchField').value
if(element=="")
{alert("please enter text");}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<input class="input" id="tbxSearchField" name="tbxSearchField" placeholder="Search" type="text" value="">
```

If anyone changes the ID of the element in browser using inspect element option then the validation doesn't work.

How to give security for this kind of situation? Is there any way to stop this from client side?

Comment: If the user was trying to get around your validations like this, they could just delete the JavaScript. You have to validate client side and server side.

Comment: Securing the data client-side only is indeed not enough :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to stop this from client side

No, there is no. Client side validation is only for users convenience. Validation logic can be changed anytime by simple editing code in browser dev tools.

> How to give security for this kind of situations?

You have **always** to revalidate data from client on server.

Answer (score 0):

Well **the best way to securily validate inputs is to use Server Side validation**, but with **jQuery** you can avoid using `id` or `class` to validate inputs:

```
var elements=$( "input:text" );
for(element in elements){
  if(element.val()=="")
  {
   alert("please enter text");
  }
}
```

Or you can use [**Javascript querySelector() Method**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp):

```
var elements=document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
for(element in elements){
  if(element.value=="")
  {
   alert("please enter text");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The JavaScript validations are client-side validations. The end user could easily break this with the browser's JavaScript settings.

It is best to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) validation for security purposes.

The blog post *[Form Validation Using Ajax](http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-ajax/)* will help more to use Ajax validations.